# Ubuntu not getting Installed with WSL enabled

Tags: boot, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I was trying to install Ubuntu after enabling WSL in my Laptop with Windows 11. It shows as installed but on opening it shows the following error

```
WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x8004032d
Error: 0x8004032d (null)
Press any key to continue...
```

What to do I have uninstalled and reinstalled Ubuntu several times. But the error persists and Ubuntu does not open Please provide a solution

Comment: This seems more to be a Windows problem than an Ubuntu one, since it is Windowserror-codes. Try asking Microsoft support.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

Follow / check the steps mentioned in https://aka.ms/wsl2kernel.

Then download there "WSL2 Linux kernel update package for x64 machines" and install as administrator the .msi file.

Found that here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1424692/how-to-fix-wslregisterdistribution-failed-with-err